# Move text to center top of div, without making div smaller

Tags: html, css

So I have tried a few of the suggestions on other posts, but I seem to just be forcing my entire image area to get smaller when I move the text to the top center of the header area.

I want to place the 'we are..' text to the top center (yellow text over the image).  I have tried using padding/margins and also align-content, but it just forces the whole area to get smaller.. any suggestions on how I can force the text upwards?

Here is [the page](http://outside.hobhob.uk/about.html)

Here is the code for the areas section:

```
 <section class="meta-wrapper parallax" style="background-image: url('content/about_bg.png');" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.6" data-stellar-vertical-offset="20">
            <div id="page_header">
                <div class="container text-center">
                    <h2><span>We are</span><br>Outside The Line</h2>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end page_header -->
        </section><!-- end section -->
```

Here is the CSS I am looking at editing (this controls the text position but also is the container.. so I am not sure if I should be doing something to the H2 tags or maybe making up a new CSS tag for this?

```
#page_header h2 {
    color:#fff;
    border-bottom:0 !important;
    font-size:50px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#page_header h2 span {
    font-size:60px;
    border:3px solid #fff;
    padding:4px 20px;
}

#page_header .container-fluid h2 {
    left:10%;
    bottom:15%;
    position: absolute;
```

I had tried vertical-align etc, but this just does nothing.. I am guessing I need to play around with the padding etc, but I seem to be getting a little stuck at getting this to move without moving everything else..

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
#page_header{
    padding:30rem 0 ;
}
```

to this:

```
#page_header {
    padding: 0 0 60rem;
}
```

The idea is to preserve the total amount of padding (`60rem`) but move all the padding to the bottom instead of evenly on the top and bottom.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great, but pushed it a little too high, but this has made things clearer on where I need to go with my edits.  Thanks loads :)

Answer (score 1):

replace your css like this:

```
#page_header .container {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 45%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to push it to the top right corner oddly.. but I should be able to push it about with this code :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly thanks for the help from the two who answered.

After playing around with the #page_header I managed to get the title to show up where I wanted.

The code I used was;

```
    #page_header
    {
        padding: 10rem 0 60rem!important;
    }
```